# Cucumber/Selenium throwing more detailed errors when element not found

Tags: selenium, cucumber, runtime-error, element

Is there a way for Selenium/Cucumber to throw a more descriptive error when an element is not found? Currently it only throws:

The element could not be found (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

I'd like to also include the locator.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your test fixture code is designed and structured. You can wrap FindElement code inside try/catch block. Something like:

```
Public void TestMethod(string elementId)
{
  try
  {
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementId)); 
  }
  catch(NoSuchElementException exception)
  {
    Assert.Fail("Can't find the element in the page. The element is: " +elementId)
  }
 }
```